# Read string variables into variables

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have three keywords `%vel`, `%note`, `%blah` that I want to parse from strings into integers:

```
s = "%vel=127, %note=64,     %blah=13"

# should give { 'vel': 127, 'note': 64,  'blah': 13}
# or vel = 127 // note = 64 //  blah = 13
```

or

```
s = "%blah=5,%note=44"
# should give { 'blah': 5, 'note': 44}
```

I have done something like:

```
s = "%vel=127, %note=64,     %blah=13"
d = dict()
for k in s.split(','):
    k = k.strip()
    if "%vel" in k: d['vel'] = int(k.split("%vel=")[1])
    if "%note" in k: d['note'] = int(k.split("%note=")[1])
    if "%blah" in k: d['blah'] = int(k.split("%blah=")[1])
print d
```

It works, but I find it quite ugly.

**How to do this in a nicer / pythonic way?**

Comment: Use Regular expression groups

Comment: I have flagged this as "nicer" is opinion based. Make your question more specific.

Comment: @HiteshDharamdasani : do you have an example? Will it be shorter then the current code?

Comment: What you are looking for is "How to get rid of those `if`s and "magic" strings?"

Comment: @khajvah you're right: I mean I'm looking for a solution more robust to edge cases, looking for something that would be more natural do such jobs, such as a built-in module doing this maybe?

Comment: @Basj You are looking for a solution that is generic. I.e. it will work not only for `%vel %note %blah` but for any keyword that has form `%string=number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really quick list comprehension example:

```
s = "%blah=5, %note=44"
print dict([item.split('=') for item in s.replace(' ','').replace('%', '').split(',')])
```

## Edit:

```
s = "%blah=5, %note=44"
# existing dict
old_dict_with_data = { ... }     
result = dict(map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], [item.split('=') for item in s.replace(' ', '').replace('%', '').split(',')]))
old_dict_with_data.update(result)
```

I'd suggest split this comprehension stuff to a few operations because I admit it doesn't look very readable :(

Please fill free to ask, I will explain it

Comment: great! and if we assume the dict was already created before, with some other values in it, can we modify your code to update the dict?

Comment: Super! a small question: why does `.replace(' ', '')` work but not  `.strip()`  (i tried)

Comment: I also added a fix to convert all values to int.

Comment: Because strip removes whitespaces only from begin and end of the string

Comment: I will probably use your previous version: `print dict([item.split('=') for item in s.replace(' ','').replace('%', '').split(',')])`

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy with regular expressions:

**Example:**

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> s = "%vel=127, %note=64,     %blah=13"
>>> m = findall("%([a-z]+)=([0-9]+)", s)
>>> d = dict(m)
>>> d
{'note': '64', 'blah': '13', 'vel': '127'}
```

You can even turn the integer values into proper `int`(s):

```
>>> dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in m)
{'note': 64, 'blah': 13, 'vel': 127}
```

Comment: And it is actually looks not so horrible as my solution. Nice!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with regular expressions and a little functional programming to go with it. Makes for a very readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why nobody is doing a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> s = "%blah=5, %note=44"
>>> {k: int(v) for k, v in (item[1:].split('=') for item in s.split(', '))}
{'note': 44, 'blah': 5}
```

Edit: For the misformatted case:

```
>>> s = "%vel=127, %note=64,     %blah=13"
>>> {k: int(v) for k, v in (item.strip()[1:].split('=') for item in s.split(','))}
{'vel': 127, 'note': 64, 'blah': 13}
```

Comment: s = "%vel=127, %note=64,     %blah=13"
for this you need to strip the whitespace else you would get something like this
{'   %blah': 13, 'note': 64, 'vel': 127}

Comment: @Ajay Thanks, fixed. That's what I get for copying the example from the accepted answer :-P

Answer (score 0):

Why not using list comprehension?

```
key_val_list = [k.strip().split('=') for k in s.split(',')]
for item in key_val_list:
    d[item[0][1:]] = int(item[1])
```

Comment: There you go! I don't understand why people downvoted. I didn't have time to elaborate and got knocked out for that :(

Comment: I upvoted now! I think they downvoted because they thought your first version of the answer was more a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
In [101]: dict(map(lambda v: v.replace('%','').split('='), map(str.strip, s.split(','))))
Out[101]: {'blah': '13', 'note': '64', 'vel': '127'}
```

In case, your `dict` already exists just assign the result to that variable.